# iOS .stringsdict not working

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm trying to use the .stringsdict functionality in iOS programming to display the proper ordinal suffix (st, nd, rd, etc...) for numbers.  I've created the .stringsdict file for english, but it's only using the 'one' and 'other' keys.  It's ignoring the 'two' and 'few' options.  Anybody see what i've done wrong here?

The file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>TEAM_RANK_ORDINAL</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@ordinal_string@</string>
        <key>ordinal_string</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>lu</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%lust</string>
            <key>two</key>
            <string>%lund</string>
            <key>few</key>
            <string>%lurd</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%luth</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I then access it like so, from Swift.  For the value 1 it appends st, but every other number appends th:

```swift
    let fmt = NSLocalizedString("TEAM_RANK_ORDINAL", comment: "")
    for i in 0...30 {
        println(String(format: fmt, i))
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The english locale ignores the "two" and "few" rules and uses
only "one" and "other".

See [Plural Rule Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH16-SW4) in the "Internationalization and Localization Guide":

> The meaning of the categories is language-dependent, and not all
>   languages have the same categories.
>
> For example, English only uses the `one`, and `other` categories to
>   represent plural forms. Arabic has different plural forms for the
>   `zero`, `one`, `two`, `few`, `many`, and `other` categories. ...

There is (as far as I know) no way to use a .stringsdict file
for producing ordinal numbers.

Comment: Yah, I just found that.  Makes the stringsdict file a big complicated mess for very little gain.  Sigh.  I hope they extend it to be more useful going forward.  I just submitted an enhancement request.

Comment: The categories are not arbitrary; they are defined by Unicode. See http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html. The primary purpose of stringsdict is to make grammatically correct pluralization possible in languages *other than* English. As a side benefit it removes the need to have an if/else check for having a separate singular string.

Comment: @Gargoyle Any luck with your enhancement request? :)

Comment: you save my day!

Answer (score 5):

While Martin answered your `stringsdict` question, for users who stumble across the "ordinal" issue, one should just use `NumberFormatter` for localized ordinal numbers. E.g.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal

for i in 1..<30 {
    print(formatter.string(for: i) ?? i)
}
```

Producing (for English users):

> 1st
>   2nd
>   3rd
>   4th
>   5th
>   6th
>   7th
>   8th
>   9th
>   10th
>   11th
>   12th
>   13th
>   14th
>   15th
>   16th
>   17th
>   18th
>   19th
>   20th
>   21st
>   22nd
>   23rd
>   24th
>   25th
>   26th
>   27th
>   28th
>   29th

And, FWIW, even if the `stringsdict` approach worked for `two`, etc., doesn't have a prayer of differentiating between large numbers that use a different ordinality syntax, e.g. between 122nd and 124th. You really need to use `NumberFormatter` for this.